# django recognizing "post" as "get"

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

All my "post" actions are being recognized as "get" I have tried everything I know to fix this but everything seems to be in order. Submitting the form returns "GET" every time.

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',
 url(r'^buildit/$', 'main.apps.builder.views.main'),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def main(request):
  return HttpResponse(request.method)
```

html form

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="audio"/> Audio<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="list" value="video"/> Video<br />
<input type="submit" value="Get Custom Library!" /> 
</form>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#myform").submit(function() {



    serialize = $(this).serialize()

    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/django/builder/buildit',
    data: serialize,
    crossDomain: false,
    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
});

    return false;

    $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
function sameOrigin(url) {
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}
function safeMethod(method) {
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

if (!safeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
}
});

});
});
```

Comment: You might try outputting the contents of `request.method` rather than just "not post"; it'd probably help with your debugging.

Comment: Shot in the dark: have you tried adding `method="post"` to your html form?

Comment: @Hannele it wouldn't matter. The ajax function is explicitly defining the method.

Comment: I set my HttpResponse `request.method` and it returned `GET`

Comment: Can you please inspect the XHR request with a Webeditor (standard in IE9/Chrome, Firebug in Firefox) and see what the request and response body's are?

Comment: @user1442957 Let's change the `TYPE` for ALL ajax requests. `$.ajaxSetup({type : 'POST' });` -- any change?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy http://i.imgur.com/wmOlx.jpg and no it still says "GET"

Comment: @user1442957 Django's a fickle woman sometimes. You're not by chance running Django with PHP are you?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy no im not its just django and mod_wsgi. I have another urls.py in my main projects folder that points to my app's urls.py. Could the urls.py have anything to do with this?

Comment: There is a `return false;` that seems very weird for me. Probably the csfr protection is not being executed, however the error would be different. I recommend to put the csfr protection code at the beginning of the javascript.

Comment: @user1442957 now I'm no expert on Django here...but it seems like Django will override any requests if there is an Append_Slash issue. It will redirect the request with the slash appended at the end, at this point, it will lose any `POST` information and will return the `GET` method. Maybe try putting a `/` at the end of `/django/builder/buildit`? Shot in the dark... (Would seem this only matters if APPEND_SLASH = false...)

Comment: lol your "shot in the dark" fixed the issue. Sometimes the little things are the hardest to solve. thanks for all your help and post an answer to this so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I'm no expert on Django here...but it seems like Django will override any requests if there is an Append_Slash issue. It will redirect the request with the slash appended at the end, at this point, it will lose any POST information and will return the GET method. Maybe try putting a / at the end of /django/builder/buildit? Shot in the dark... (Would seem this only matters if APPEND_SLASH = false...)

Answer (score 2):

might as well put it in your form

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
```

It's hard to read the javascript that is strangely indented. But, why is there code after `return false;` without closing the submit callback?

Comment: No reason. he's explicitly defined the `POST` method in ajax.

Comment: it's still poor form. It would be nice if it would work without javascript perhaps. Also, I would bet that the submit would start POSTing with this change because of some other error.

Comment: i believe the "return false;" is to stop the form from actually submitting. @Ohgodwhy it doesn't matter if they define POST in ajax, if the form actually submits, then ajax is canceled and it's all pointless. the "return false;" is necessary to do what the OP wants.

Comment: @skyl and its not poor form. the OP wants to submit the form with ajax...that's their decision. you can't use ajax without javascript, so what's your suggestion?

Comment: @ianpgall I never said anything about `return false` because it was obvious what the point of it was. Also, @skyl is saying that if the user `does not support javascript it would be nice to have an alternative for graceful degradation.` Jeeze, lots of finger pointer's and name callers 'round here lately.

Comment: I know what the return false is supposed to do **why is there code after return false; without closing the submit callback** @ianpgall Having a form that is meant to `post` without a `method` in the tag is poor form imo. And yes, @Ohgodwhy is correct in recognizing my allusion to graceful degradation / progressive enhancement.

Comment: hey hey now, i was pointing fingers or anything, i just wanted to discuss the situation and had to describe different things to different people. my conclusion: i didn't understand a few things in your comments before but now i do, so i apologize for misunderstanding. i didn't realize that the code comes after "return false;" without closing something. and i understand about how have it degrade gracefully.

Comment: and i think that if the OP wanted only async submitting to happen, they shouldn't have used an incomplete form tag - just don't use one at all. but if they are going to include one, at least include the method and action. if they want it to degrade gracefully, then they would be necessary anyways. sorry again for misreading/misunderstanding