# get vs post Django forms

Tags: django, http

Im trying to understand the GET vs POST using a Django application and encountering the following issues,

Even though the `method="post"` in the `search_form.html` when I enter something and enter submit, it is passing a GET method as I see the parameters being passed in the url.. Even the request.GET is able to access the value.

I thought only based on what you give in METHOD determines if it is `GET` or `POST`.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
        url(r'^meta/',views.display_meta,name='meta'),
        url(r'^search-form/$',views.search_form),
                url(r'^search/$',views.search),
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        message = 'You searched for :%r' % request.GET['q']
    else:
        message = 'You submitted an empty form'

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

search_form.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/search/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026257/django-recognizing-post-as-get?rq=1

Comment: I tried it but still its not working

Comment: ignore my question..I had same copy of the form in different places and debugging the wrong place..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the request method with:

```
request.META.get('REQUEST_METHOD')
```

Btw. you should consider using [generic views for stuff like search forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView), which is much easier.

Comment: it is GET even though I have given POST